# default everything plus a plane under the default cube, why does shadow not reach corner of cube?

Tags: shadows

With a very basic first render test, I do not find that the shadow looks right.  What am I missing about the default render settings, or my expectations about what Blender should be doing here?

Blender 2.83, start from File > Defaults > Load Factory Settings, and File > New > General (default cube, default camera, default light, default all render settings).

Add a 10x10 plane immediately below (touching) the cube: shift a (to add) > Mesh > Plane, g (grab) z -1 enter to move it down, s (scale) x 10 enter, s y 10 enter.

F12 to render.  The shadow does not look right at the front corner. [image: render with wrong-looking shadow]

Here is zoomed view of cube and its shadow on the plane.[image: zoomed image of wrong-looking shadow]  This makes it look like the cube is levitated slightly off the plane.  However I checked in edit mode that all bottom layer points on the cube are indeed at z=-1, and all corner points of the plane are at z=-1. (well in edit mode they are at z=0, and the object moved to z=-1; I also repeated the test doing the grab and scale all in edit mode, the odd shadow is the same).

After this very basic from-factory test, I also looked for settings like super-sampling on the render, or the "point" light was actually an area light, etc, but could find none of such changes that fixed this wrong-looking shadow.  Can someone explain what I'm missing?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/275416/eevee-displays-shadows-as-though-they-levitate

Comment: @scurest thanks for pointing that out.  It certainly seems to be "peter panning shadows".  Cube Size and Contact Shadows did help but other of those tips didn't.

Comment: Also https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277509/35559